What's different between ElButton and el-button in element-plus use in vue
In element-plus official docs, component was imported by this way: ElButton, and used by this way: el-button.
In my practice, use element-plus in this way: ElButton can also work normally.
I wander what's the difference between these two way to use element-plus component in deep, will it has affective to the development in the future?

In shorts, there's no different. Just be consistent in your project.
If you write template in SFC you can use both, but it's recommended to use PascalCase to differentiate from native HTML elements.
If you use in-DOM template, you must use kebab-case (<el-button></el-button>)
Please refer to the Vue documentation for more information.
